# Repeating the emission of a Subject

Tags: typescript, rxjs, repeat, subject, switchmap

I'm not getting why the following BehaviourSeubject is not emitting three times

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const urls$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>(numbers)

urls$.pipe(repeat(3)).subscribe(console.log)
```

Also, what is the semantic of the following?

```
urls$.pipe(switchMap(arr => from(arr)), repeat(3)).subscribe(console.log)
```

I would expect to repeat three times as well but the only working case is

```
urls$.pipe(switchMap(arr => from(arr).pipe(repeat(3)))).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `[1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4]` or `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4`

Comment: besides what is being emitted I'm expecting to see the output three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of `repeat` operator,

> The `repeat(count)` operator returns an Observable that will resubscribe to the source stream when the source stream completes, at most the `count` times.

Thus, the source$ which is urls$ in this case needs to be completed so that repeat can act, but urls$ is a behavior subject and once you signal completion for the behavior subject with `urls$.complete()`, you won't be able to receive anything in the subscription. Hence, if you want to have the values emitted by the behavior subject, the `repeat` operator can not be used.

Now how do we solve this problem?

The `expand` operator comes to our rescue. `[expand][1]` recursively projects the values emitted by the source observable. With `expand` & `take`, we'll be able to achieve the desired result.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const urls$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>(numbers);

urls$
  .pipe(expand(result => urls$), take(3))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: what if I need the subject to repeat endlessly?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Then you don't use the take operator.

Comment: ok but without adding a `delay` to the return value of the `expand` I will get a maximum call stack size exceeded error, is adding a delay a correct solution?